# Symfony2 HHVM 3.4 Serializer Issue

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, hhvm

We're testing our Symfony2 API on a HHVM. We just return php objects in our controllers, which will be serialized into Json.

Each object has a config file, in which we are defining, which data to expose. On PHP 5.4/5.5/5.6 everything runs fine, but on the HVVM, the serializer ignores the serializer config files. It just serializes all properties.

```
    {
    "simple_products":{
        "_new": false,
        "_deleted": false,
        "modified_columns":[],
        "virtual_columns":[],
        "id": "3556",
        "daytime_id": "1",
        "name": "Banane",
        "value": 123,
        "peer": null,
        "start_copy": false,
        "day_id": "11561",
        "created_at": "2015-01-13 17:36:38",
        "updated_at": "2015-01-13 17:36:38",
        "created_by": "3505",
        "updated_by": "3505",
        "a_day": null,
        "a_daytime": null,
        "already_in_save": false,
        "already_in_validation": false,
        "already_in_clear_all_references_deep": false,
        "validation_failures":[]
    }
}
```

instead of just

```
{
    "simple_products":{
        "id": "4181",
        "daytime_id": "1",
        "name": "Banane",
        "value": 123
    }
}
```

Anyone know what to do? If you need config files, feel free to ask.

### Update (jms/serializer config)

```
# jms serializer config
jms_serializer:
    property_naming:
        lower_case: true
    metadata:
        cache: file
        debug: "%kernel.debug%"
        file_cache:
            dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            propel:
                namespace_prefix: ""
                path: "@FooRestBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
    visitors:
        json:
            options: 0
```

Comment: What kind of serializer is that? Some library? Your own? How does it read the config files?

Comment: Hey, its the jms/serializer. I'll push config in the main post.

Comment: Try to set the json_encode options bitmask in the jms_serializer config. Maybe HHVM uses other defaults.

Comment: :( Nope, same as before. I'll update my config above. Any other ideas? :'(

Comment: It seems, that the serializer expects another config file for each object. Without hvvm he just needs the base logic: Model.Module.Entity.om.BaseEntity, Now it also needs Model.Module.Entity.Entity which extends the base class. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using jms serializer to serialize your object using annotations. HHVM is ignoring annotations in docblocks. Try to define your serialization rules in an xml:

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/xml_reference